# Change value in json, when other value is looking for

Tags: c#, json, list

I have Json where i have 2 objects. I would like to know how to change value in my json, when other value is looking for. For example i would like to change "speciality" to "Warrior" for Person who's "Name" is Harry.
**It's my Json**

```
{
  "Person": [
    {
      "Speciality": "Archer",
      "Id": 432742,
      "Name": "Charlie",
      "Surname": "Evans",
      "Items": [
        "Bow",
        "Arrow",
      ]
    },
    {
      "Speciality": "Soldier",
      "Id": 432534,
      "Name": "Harry",
      "Surname": "Thomas",
      "Items": [
        "Gun",
        "Knife",
     ]
    }
  ],
  "Monster": [
    {
      "Name": "Papua",
      "Skills": [
        "Jump",
        "SlowWalk",
      ]
    },
    {
     "Name": "Geot",
     "Skills": [
        "Run",
        "Push",
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**My classes**

```
public class Person
{
    public string Speciality { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Monster
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Skills { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Person> People { get; set; }
    public List<Monster> Monsters { get; set; }
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(jsonfile)
for (int i = 0; i < result.People.Count; ++i)
{
    result.Where(w => w.Person.Name == "Harry").ToList().ForEach(s => s.Person.Speciality = "Warrior");
}
```

Thanks in advance for some help.

Comment: Strictly speaking JSON is a string and you would have to do a string replace. https://www.json.org/json-en.html  or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Comment: The names in your models don't match up to the json, is that a typo? `{"Person": [ ... ]` != `class Root { public List<Person> People `

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson My bad, Do you know how to help me with change values?

Comment: You can edit your post to fix any typos. Also, is `Lekarze` in your for-loop also a typo or missed translation? The json and the models don't contain that word. I recommend when you ask C# questions on Stack Overflow, double check your sample code on a site like dotnetfiddle.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can use foreach loop

```
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(jsonfile);
foreach (var person in result.Person)
{
  if(person.Name == "Harry"){
     person.Speciality = "";
  }
}
```